# how do I extract some rows of an array by having an array of index?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an array and I could find the index of rows of that array that have specific value. now I want to extract all these rows in new array.I used the following code but it produces an error:

```
finding_all_infValue=np.asarray(BD[BD.min(axis=1) != np.inf])
indx=np.where([BD.min(axis=1) == np.inf])[1]
new_array=BD[indx,:]
```

what should I do to extract these rows?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming indx contains an array of indices, you should be able to do:

```
[BD[x] for x in indx]
```

which will loop thru your indx list and index BD based on each element.